# Solving $\operatorname{cis} x \operatorname{cis} 2x \operatorname{cis} 3x \dots \operatorname{cis} nx=1$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Given the equation:

$$\operatorname{cis} x \operatorname{cis} 2x \operatorname{cis} 3x \dots \operatorname{cis} nx=1$$

How can I solve it?

I know that $\operatorname{cis} x=\cos x+i\sin x$, but I can't see how to proceed from there.

Thank you

Comment: For constant $a$, $\cos a x + i \sin a x = e^{iax}$

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I'll try. Thanks

Comment: Also, another hint would be to know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k=n(n+1)/2$

Comment: I got: $ix(1+n)(n/2)=1$. So I need to square both sides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\def\cis{\operatorname{cis}}\cis$ function obeys a very simple rule:
$$
\cis a\cis b=\cis(a+b)
$$
Just apply the decomposition $\cis a=\cos a+i\sin a$, in order to prove it. Then you have
$$
\cis(x+2x+\dots+nx)=1
$$
and now it should be easy.

Hint: $x+2x+\dots+nx=x\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so you have
$$
\cis\frac{n(n+1)x}{2}=\cis0
$$

Comment: But then: $n(n+1)=0, x=0$ but isn't a period for $cis$?

Comment: @Karen $\cis a=\cis b$ means $a=b+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Got it. So $x=4\pi k/n(n+1)$, and $k=0,1,...,n$?

Comment: @Karen Almost. `;-)` Check the $2$'s

Comment: I'm not sure about the k's.

Comment: @Karen No, $k$ can be *any* integer, unless you are requested to find $x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: So there is no restrictions about the number of solutions for this equation?

Comment: @Karen It's like $\sin x=1/2$, isn't it?

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help:)

Comment: If $x\in [0,2\pi)$, $0\leq \frac{4\pi k}{n(n+1)} \leq 2\pi \implies k=0,1,\ldots, \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$